# Showing gif in android

Tags: android, gif, movie

i have this code to show gif image with Movie.

```
public class GIFView extends View{        
private Movie movie;  
private InputStream is;  
private long moviestart;  
public GIFView(Context context) {  
    super(context);
    is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.anim_cerca);  
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
}  

@Override  
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  

    if (moviestart == 0) 
        moviestart = now;  

    int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
    movie.setTime(relTime);
    movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
    this.invalidate();
}                         

}
```

My problem borns when gif is loaded, it draw very bad, only the first frame is shown and the other are like disturbed. What can i do?

**EDIT:** THE PROBLEM IS EMULATOR! IT DOESN'T SHOW GIF, BUT ON DEVICE IT'S OK! :)

Comment: see this post , http://www.anddev.org/how_to_play_gif_file_in_android-t3492.html , hope it helps

Comment: It's not good cause it use a class GIFDecoder.. and i don't know how to custom it for my use..

Comment: Wonder if it would work better in assets instead of resources, as the build system reserves the right to reformat your assets to optimise them.

Comment: please write the answer in the box at the end of the page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved in this way :

```
public class GIFView extends View{        
    private Movie movie;    
    private long moviestart;  
    public GIFView(Context context) throws IOException {  
        super(context);
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("anim_cerca.gif"));
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException{
        super(context, attrs);
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("anim_cerca.gif"));
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        movie=Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("anim_cerca.gif"));
    }
@Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (moviestart == 0) 
            moviestart = now;
            int relTime;
            relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
            movie.setTime(relTime);
            movie.draw(canvas,0,0);
            this.invalidate();
       }                         
}
```

and in layout i put this custom view in this way:

```
<spazio.digitale.com.GIFView
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/GIFSingle">
</spazio.digitale.com.GIFView>
```

Comment: What is spazio.digitale? is it lib or api?

Comment: @Titanic it is package path in your own code, the path to class implementing View subclass named GIFView. I know you've already figured that out, but just for case ;)

Comment: do u know the way to scale down big gif so it fit to screen properly.. the thing is that we are using one gif animation on different screens, cause we are keeping it in assets, so scaling should be done from code somehow.. but how..?

Comment: how can i change the size of the movie, when i draw it in java code?

Comment: android:layout_width="YOURDP" android:layout_height="YOURDP"

Comment: i mean i want to change the size of the GIF picture in the JAVA view class in the onDraw() method

Comment: @JackTurky but what should I do if gif is too big for canvas? Right now with this code it just goes out of screen

Comment: Somehow this doesnt work for me. It gives error /libc(20288): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 20288 (.track.driv)
any suggestion?

Answer (score 11):

Good start. 
Gotta make it more useful for loading different gifs after being added to the view and for either assets or resources. Also, for devices with hardware acceleration I was getting blank views, so I turned it off for this GIFView.

Also, be sure to put animated gifs in the res/drawable-xhdpi directory (or assets if using that way)

```
public class GIFView extends View{

    Movie movie;
    long moviestart;

    public GIFView(Context context) throws IOException { 
        super(context);
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException{
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void loadGIFResource(Context context, int id)
    {
        //turn off hardware acceleration
        this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        InputStream is=context.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public void loadGIFAsset(Context context, String filename)
    {
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = context.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);
            movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (movie == null) {
            return;
        }

        long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (moviestart == 0) moviestart = now;

        int relTime;
        relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
imageView.loadGIFResource(this, R.drawable.quickguide_1);
```

**and**

```
<com.eyeverify.GIFView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/quickguide_1"/>
```

Comment: i tried your code it displays the GIF but the size is very small, not getting why so ?

Answer (score 2):

create a class GifDecoder class

```
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.util.Vector;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;  
     import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
     public class GifDecoder
    {


    public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
    /**
     * File read status: Error decoding file (may be partially decoded)
     */

    public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
    /**
     * File read status: Unable to open source.
     */

    public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;
    protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096*2;
    public static final    int MIN_DELAY                   = 100;
    public static final    int MIN_DELAY_ENFORCE_THRESHOLD = 20;
    protected InputStream in;
    protected int status;
    protected int width; // full image width
    protected int height; // full image height
    protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
    protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
    protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
    protected int[] gct; // global color table
    protected int[] lct; // local color table
    protected int[] act; // active color table
    protected int bgIndex; // background color index
    protected int bgColor; // background color
    protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
    protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
    protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
    protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
    protected int lctSize; // local color table size
    protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
    protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
    protected Bitmap image; // current frame
    protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
    protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
    protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
    protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
    protected int lastDispose = 0;
    protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
    protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
    protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
    // LZW decoder working arrays

    protected short[] prefix;
    protected byte[] suffix;
    protected byte[] pixelStack;
    protected byte[] pixels;
    protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; 
    protected int frameCount;
    private boolean readComplete;

    public GifDecoder()
    {
        readComplete = false;
    }

    private static class GifFrame {
        public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
            image = im;
            delay = del;
        }

        public Bitmap image;
        public int delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets display duration for specified frame.
     *
     * @param n
     *          int index of frame
     * @return delay in milliseconds
     */
    public int getDelay(int n) {
        delay = -1;
        if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
            delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
            //meets browser compatibility standards
            if (delay < MIN_DELAY_ENFORCE_THRESHOLD) delay = MIN_DELAY;
        }
        return delay;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the number of frames read from file.
     *
     * @return frame count
     */
    public int getFrameCount() {
        return frameCount;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first (or only) image read.
     *
     * @return BufferedBitmap containing first frame, or null if none.
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return getFrame(0);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the "Netscape" iteration count, if any. A count of 0 means repeat indefinitiely.
     *
     * @return iteration count if one was specified, else 1.
     */
    public int getLoopCount() {
        return loopCount;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new frame image from current data (and previous frames as specified by their disposition codes).
     */
    protected void setPixels() {
        // expose destination image's pixels as int array
        int[] dest = new int[width * height];
        // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
        if (lastDispose > 0) {
            if (lastDispose == 3) {
                // use image before last
                int n = frameCount - 2;
                if (n > 0) {
                    lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                } else {
                    lastBitmap = null;
                }
            }
            if (lastBitmap != null) {
                lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                // copy pixels
                if (lastDispose == 2) {
                    // fill last image rect area with background color
                    int c = 0;
                    if (!transparency) {
                        c = lastBgColor;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                        int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                        int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                        for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                            dest[k] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
        int pass = 1;
        int inc = 8;
        int iline = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
            int line = i;
            if (interlace) {
                if (iline >= ih) {
                    pass++;
                    switch (pass) {
                    case 2:
                        iline = 4;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        iline = 2;
                        inc = 4;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        iline = 1;
                        inc = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                line = iline;
                iline += inc;
            }
            line += iy;
            if (line < height) {
                int k = line * width;
                int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                    dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                }
                int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                while (dx < dlim) {
                    // map color and insert in destination
                    int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                    int c = act[index];
                    if (c != 0) {
                        dest[dx] = c;
                    }
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the image contents of frame n.
     *
     * @return BufferedBitmap representation of frame, or null if n is invalid.
     */
    public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
        if (frameCount <= 0)
            return null;
        n = n % frameCount;
        return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF image from stream
     *
     * @param is
     *          containing GIF file.
     * @return read status code (0 = no errors)
     */
    public int read(InputStream is)
    {
        init();
        if (is != null) {
            in = is;
            readHeader();
            if (!err()) {
                readContents();
                if (frameCount < 0) {
                    status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                }
            }
        } else {
            status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
        }
        readComplete = true;
        return status;
    }

    public void complete()
    {
        readContents();
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decodes LZW image data into pixel array. Adapted from John Cristy's BitmapMagick.
     */
    protected void decodeBitmapData() {
        int nullCode = -1;
        int npix = iw * ih;
        int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
        if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
            pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
        }
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (suffix == null) {
            suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
        }
        if (pixelStack == null) {
            pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
        }
        // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
        data_size = read();
        clear = 1 << data_size;
        end_of_information = clear + 1;
        available = clear + 2;
        old_code = nullCode;
        code_size = data_size + 1;
        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
        for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
            prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            suffix[code] = (byte) code;
        }
        // Decode GIF pixel stream.
        datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
            if (top == 0) {
                if (bits < code_size) {
                    // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                    if (count == 0) {
                        // Read a new data block.
                        count = readBlock();
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        bi = 0;
                    }
                    datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                    bits += 8;
                    bi++;
                    count--;
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the next code.
                code = datum & code_mask;
                datum >>= code_size;
                    bits -= code_size;
                    // Interpret the code
                    if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (code == clear) {
                        // Reset decoder.
                        code_size = data_size + 1;
                        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                        available = clear + 2;
                        old_code = nullCode;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (old_code == nullCode) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                        old_code = code;
                        first = code;
                        continue;
                    }
                    in_code = code;
                    if (code == available) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                        code = old_code;
                    }
                    while (code > clear) {
                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                        code = prefix[code];
                    }
                    first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                    // Add a new string to the string table,
                    if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                        break;
                    }
                    pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                    prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                    suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                    available++;
                    if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                        code_size++;
                        code_mask += available;
                    }
                    old_code = in_code;
            }
            // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
            top--;
            pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
            i++;
        }
        for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if an error was encountered during reading/decoding
     */
    protected boolean err() {
        return status != STATUS_OK;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes or re-initializes reader
     */
    protected void init() {
        status = STATUS_OK;
        frameCount = 0;
        frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
        gct = null;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a single byte from the input stream.
     */
    protected int read() {
        int curByte = 0;
        try {
            curByte = in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        }
        return curByte;
    }

    /**
     * Reads next variable length block from input.
     *
     * @return number of bytes stored in "buffer"
     */
    protected int readBlock() {
        blockSize = read();
        int n = 0;
        if (blockSize > 0) {
            try {
                int count = 0;
                while (n < blockSize) {
                    count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    n += count;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (n < blockSize) {
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    /**
     * Reads color table as 256 RGB integer values
     *
     * @param ncolors
     *          int number of colors to read
     * @return int array containing 256 colors (packed ARGB with full alpha)
     */
    protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
        int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
        int[] tab = null;
        byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = in.read(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (n < nbytes) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
        } else {
            tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < ncolors) {
                int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
        return tab;
    }

    /**
     * Main file parser. Reads GIF content blocks.
     */
    protected void readContents() {
        // read GIF file content blocks
        boolean done = false;
        while (!(done || err())) {
            int code = read();
            switch (code) {
            case 0x2C: // image separator
            readBitmap();
            if(!readComplete) return;
            break;
            case 0x21: // extension
                code = read();
                switch (code) {
                case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                    readGraphicControlExt();
                    break;
                case 0xff: // application extension
                    readBlock();
                    String app = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                        app += (char) block[i];
                    }
                    if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                        readNetscapeExt();
                    } else {
                        skip(); // don't care
                    }
                    break;
                case 0xfe:// comment extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                case 0x01:// plain text extension
                    skip();
                    break;
                default: // uninteresting extension
                    skip();
                }
                break;
            case 0x3b: // terminator
                done = true;
                break;
            case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
            default:
                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads Graphics Control Extension values
     */
    protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
        read(); // block size
        int packed = read(); // packed fields
        dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
                    if (dispose == 0) {
                        dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
                    }
                    transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
                    delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
                    transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
                    read(); // block terminator
    }

    /**
     * Reads GIF file header information.
     */
    protected void readHeader() {
        String id = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            id += (char) read();
        }
        if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
            return;
        }
        readLSD();
        if (gctFlag && !err()) {
            gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
            bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads next frame image
     */
    protected void readBitmap() {
        ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
        iy = readShort();
        iw = readShort();
        ih = readShort();
        int packed = read();
        lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
        lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
        // 3 - sort flag
        // 4-5 - reserved lctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 - local color
        // table size
        interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
        if (lctFlag) {
            lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
            act = lct; // make local table active
        } else {
            act = gct; // make global table active
            if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                bgColor = 0;
            }
        }
        int save = 0;
        if (transparency) {
            save = act[transIndex];
            act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
        }
        if (act == null) {
            status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
        }
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
        skip();
        if (err()) {
            return;
        }
        frameCount++;
        // create new image to receive frame data
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
        setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
        frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
        // list
        if (transparency) {
            act[transIndex] = save;
        }
        resetFrame();
    }

    /**
     * Reads Logical Screen Descriptor
     */
    protected void readLSD() {
        // logical screen size
        width = readShort();
        height = readShort();
        // packed fields
        int packed = read();
        gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
        // 2-4 : color resolution
        // 5 : gct sort flag
        gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
        bgIndex = read(); // background color index
        pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
    }

    /**
     * Reads Netscape extenstion to obtain iteration count
     */
    protected void readNetscapeExt() {
        do {
            readBlock();
            if (block[0] == 1) {
                // loop count sub-block
                int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
            }
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }

    /**
     * Reads next 16-bit value, LSB first
     */
    protected int readShort() {
        // read 16-bit value, LSB first
        return read() | (read() << 8);
    }

    /**
     * Resets frame state for reading next image.
     */
    protected void resetFrame() {
        lastDispose = dispose;
        lrx = ix;
        lry = iy;
        lrw = iw;
        lrh = ih;
        lastBitmap = image;
        lastBgColor = bgColor;
        dispose = 0;
        transparency = false;
        delay = 0;
        lct = null;
    }

    /**
     * Skips variable length blocks up to and including next zero length block.
     */
    protected void skip() {
        do {
            readBlock();
        } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
    }
}
```

create another class GifAnimationDrawable

```
<!-- language: java -->

     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;

     import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
     import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;

      public class GifAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable
      {
      private boolean decoded;

    private GifDecoder mGifDecoder;

    private Bitmap mTmpBitmap;

    private int height, width;

    public GifAnimationDrawable(File f) throws IOException
    {
        this(f, false);
    }

    public GifAnimationDrawable(InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        this(is, false);
    }

    public GifAnimationDrawable(File f, boolean inline) throws IOException
    {
        this(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), 32768), inline);
    }

    public GifAnimationDrawable(InputStream is, boolean inline) throws IOException
    {
        super();
        InputStream bis = is;
        if(!BufferedInputStream.class.isInstance(bis)) bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 32768);
        decoded = false;
        mGifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
        mGifDecoder.read(bis);
        mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(0);
        height = mTmpBitmap.getHeight();
        width = mTmpBitmap.getWidth();
        addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(mTmpBitmap), mGifDecoder.getDelay(0));
        setOneShot(mGifDecoder.getLoopCount() != 0);
        setVisible(true, true);
        if(inline){
            loader.run();
        }else{
            new Thread(loader).start();
        }
    }

    public boolean isDecoded(){ return decoded; }

    private Runnable loader = new Runnable(){
        public void run() 
        {
            mGifDecoder.complete();
            int i, n = mGifDecoder.getFrameCount(), t;
            for(i=1;i<n;i++){
                mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(i);
                t = mGifDecoder.getDelay(i);
                addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(mTmpBitmap), t);
            }
            decoded = true;
            mGifDecoder = null;
        }
    };

    public int getMinimumHeight(){ return height; }
    public int getMinimumWidth(){ return width; }
    public int getIntrinsicHeight(){ return height; }
    public int getIntrinsicWidth(){ return width; }
}
```

in Mainactivity class create object of GifAnimationDrawable

```
 GifAnimationDrawable gif;
 try {
        gif = new GifAnimationDrawable(getResources().openRawResource(
                R.drawable.prof));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    gif.setOneShot(false);
    im1.setImageDrawable(gif);
    gif.setVisible(true, true);
```

by using these classes you can add gif file to any view

Comment: The classes that you provided is showing only the first frame and there is no animation. I tried the code on Android 4.4.4 Galaxy S3 and 5.01 Moto G.  Do I need to fix something in the code ?

Comment: I tried another GIF file and it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in your AndroidManifest.xml, set the following attribute to your Application:

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply add WebView to your xml and load the gif image inside the webview. You donot need to do anything else. The image will loop automatically inside the webview

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to use a `WebView`.

Store your animated GIF in the **assets** folder. Then load the GIF by using the following code:

`WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anim5.gif");`

`webView1` is your `WebView` id, and *anim5.gif* is your GIF name.