# Error with different screen size in android

Tags: android, size, screen

i have a gifview class that load a gif in function of screen size in this way:

```
if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL){
        gif = "anim_cerca_ldpi.gif";
    }else if((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL){
        gif = "anim_cerca_mdpi.gif";
    }else{
        gif = "anim_cerca_hdpi.gif";
    }
```

The problem is that i try it on galaxy S II and image taken is anim_cerca_ldpi.gif so the small size one. can you help me finding what could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

The much better way to do this is to create directories like `res/drawable-ldpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, etc. and put these files in the respective dirs, named `anim_cerca.gif`. Then simply load them by loading resource ID `R.drawable.anim_cerca`. It will automatically choose the right one for your device.

PS: You are checking the screen *size*, but seem to be selecting resources defined for different screen *densities*. These are different things, too.

Comment: i try to use drawable folders but i have problem with gif! if you saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777315/showing-gif-in-android i've created a class to show gif in android and it works only with file in assets and not in drawable!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't decide programmatically in this case. (I say so because of what you want to achieve with the code you posted. maybe in other cases a programmatically choice is what you'd need)

Have you tried splitting your drawables in their proper folders (`drawable-hdpi | mdpi | ldpi`)?
if you do so, android OS will load the proper resource for you.