# To show animated gifs in gridview

Tags: android, animation, gridview, animated-gif

I have written the code to show animation for single image.Now I want to display the gif images in gridview to show that animated images.Is it possible and how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it might help you.. this is a GifWebView demo.. please check it...

***mylayout.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MyLayout.java file***

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    LinearLayout toplayout;
    GifWebView view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

       toplayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toplayout);

       InputStream stream = null;
       try
       {
          stream = getAssets().open("ppp.gif");          
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }

       view = new GifWebView(this, stream);
       toplayout.addView(view);       
    }
}
```

***GifWebView.java file***

```
package com.test;

import android.content.Context;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream mStream;
    long mMoviestart;

    public GifWebView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
        super(context);
        mStream = stream;
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMoviestart == 0) {
            mMoviestart = now;
        }
        final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Put any gif file in Assets directory and give appropriate name. in this demo name is ppp.gif.

Comment: can you send it on testmumbai23@gmail.com

Comment: Download from http://www.mediafire.com/?tk3fr5r6tri3v7x link and please vote and accept if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks its working but how to get multiple means different types of images instead of single image

Comment: you can pass array of gif in LazyAdapter and bind it with Linearlayout in getView() method.

Comment: @Ajay_Addon : i need the same , can you send me the demo ??

Comment: @Ajay_Addon : yeah i tried later on and it works perfectly , but i have another issue with gif images, would you be interested to help ??

Comment: @Hussain Akhtar Wahid : why not brother. yes?

Comment: @Ajay_Addon : i wanted to change the GIF image onclick , any suggestions ??

Comment: @Hussain Akhtar Wahid : means if i click on any gif image then it is will change. right?

Comment: @Ajay_Addon : exactly , actually i need GIF images to change , on click event on a different image , but dont want to call another activity , i just want may be just the image src or something can be changed , like we dynamically change imge src

Comment: @Ajay can i get source code which you uploaded earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777315/showing-gif-in-android) and simply add it to a GridView custom cell layout.

Essentially, the *GifView* in the layout should work.