# How to make my own gallery for storing GIFs?

Tags: android, gallery, store, gif, sd-card

I have made an application which takes a video and converts it into GIF using **Animated GIF encoder.** The GIF then gets **stored** in the **SD card**.
I want to make **my own gallery** which stores all these GIFs. I am displaying the GIFs currently in **movie view** using canvas. Please tell me how to do it by giving relevant code or links. This is how I am showing GIFs from my SD card currently:
[Showing gif in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777315/showing-gif-in-android)

Comment: You could use Glide, Fresco or ion libs for displaying gifs.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What have you tried? What errors are you having? Please read the FAQ to learn more about how this site works. This isn't a "can you do this for me" kind of website. We're all about helping you, but helping you with your code that you're experiencing issues with that we can clearly reproduce and help you resolve the underlying issue.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/12/create-animated-gif-from-mp4.html
After this the gif automatically gets stored in sd card ,but i have no idea how can i store it in my own gallery.

Comment: @stan i researched and found that gif animation loading is a feature which is provided by glide. but i am a newbie so please suggest me how can i learn more about glide. i read it from here: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: There are docs available at github: https://github.com/bumptech/glide You need to create ViewPager, ListView, GridView or whatever to display there your gifs using Glide if you choose it. Since you are already >>displaying the GIFs currently in movie view using canvas<< you just need to change container from your movie view to ImageView and load your gifs into the ImageView.